# How do I connect QT 5.14.1 to MYSQL database?

Tags: mysql, sql, qt, odbc

I tried downloading the sql (sql.lib and sqld.lib) drivers to the MSCV and MINGW files ; it did not work. I then tried through QODBC3 driver and its still not connecting to the database.

I get the following error message.

> 13:20:05: Starting
>    C:\build-test1-Desktop_Qt_5_14_1_MinGW_64_bit-Debug\test1.exe ...
>   13:21:17:
>    C:\build-test1-Desktop_Qt_5_14_1_MinGW_64_bit-Debug\test1.exe exited
>    with code 0

```
    //QSqlDatabase db = QSqlDatabase::addDatabase("QODBC3","QMYSQL");
    QSqlDatabase db = QSqlDatabase::addDatabase("QODBC3","hello");
   // db.setDatabaseName("Driver={MySQL ODBC 8.0 ANSI Driver};DATABASE=hello;");
       db.setHostName("127.0.0.1");
       db.setDatabaseName("hello");
       db.setUserName("localhost");
       db.setPassword("");
       if (db.open()){
           QMessageBox::information(this,"Connection","Database connected succesfully");


       }
       else {
           QMessageBox::information(this,"Connection","Database not connected succesfully");
```

This is my code, also I     did add sql in the pro files.

Comment: which error message? Are you sure your mysql username is localhost and password is nothing?

Comment: The lines that you call an error message says the program executed correctly and finished. There was no error. code 0 means success.

Comment: But it prompts the message "database connection unsuccessful"

Comment: the odbc connects succesfully to the my sql database. However, QT does not.

Comment: "[Microsoft][ODBC Driver Manager] Data source name not found and no default driver this is the last error message

Comment: **What error message?** Do you get a popup saying "Database not connected succesfully"? Do you get any other information on the debug console? If so, **please state that in your question** (and not as a comment), we sadly cannot read your mind. Consider giving the help pages, especially on [Minimal, Reproducible Examples](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example) a read.